# Component does not show in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I do not get vue components really .... I have a vue component in my html and want to show it, but it does not show anything, what do I do wrong? 
What is the proper way to register and show a component in vue? Can someone give me a simple example for a beginner? :)

This is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="na-vue-app">
 <activity-filter>
  <template>
   'Some Text'
  </template>
 </activity-filter>
</div>
```

Vue

```
new Vue({
 el: '#na-vue-app'
});

const filterActivity = Vue.extend({
data: function () {
    return {
      distance:100,
    }
  },
  mounted() {

},
methods: {
}
});

Vue.component('activity-filter', filterActivity);
```

Comment: No, obviously I did, why would I be here otherwise? I actually took most over from the docs, and it still isn't clear to me, doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this pen: https://codepen.io/Nartub600/pen/oopBYJ

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <my-component msg="Hi!">
  </my-component>
</div>
```

JS

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  props: ['msg'],
  template: '<p>{{ msg }}</p>'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

It's the easiest form to try components I think

Comment: Thanks for the pen! Just a question here, is it possible to add the template into html instead of inside the vue component as shown in my example?
Like in between <template></template> in html?

Comment: Yes but you must use vue-loader in order to do that through Single File Components (.vue files). Try the vue-cli templates which come with everything configured out of the box.

Comment: What are those vue-cli templates good for? It seems like a lot of overhead only for defining template tags inside of html ....

Comment: Those templates are starting points for a modern javascript app using vue and are the way to go if you ask me. But of course it boils down to the scale of your app and may be too much if what you're doing is something small like a landing page.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will mark it as solved, I decided to refrain from this method, it is indeed an easier landing page, nothing fancy